# How to Create grid child elements using for loop dynamically?

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8

i'm new to windows phone development.i'm stuck with this problem. i want to create **textblock** dynamically inside the grid by using ,binding the **Json** data.
my Json data is:

```
[
  {"scheme":"SCHEME A","units":1,"amount":2000,"currency":"AED","approved_date":"2014-12-19","lockState":"Locked","id":7497,"withdrawal_request":0},

  {"scheme":"SCHEME A","units":4,"amount":100000,"currency":"INR","approved_date":"2014-12-19","lockState":"Locked","id":7543,"withdrawal_request":0}
]
```

**sample.xaml**

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,196" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.98">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TCN"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Name="aa" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{binding scheme}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Name="aa" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="UNIT"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Name="aa" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{binding unit}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Name="aa" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" />

</Grid>
  </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

**sample.xaml.cs**

```
 {
    var users = JArray.Parse(data.Result.ToString());
    tcnobjects1 = new TcnObjects1 {scheme = users[0]["scheme"].ToString(), units  = users[0]["units"].ToString(), amount = users[0]["amount"].ToString(), currency = users[0]["currency"].ToString(), lockState = users[0]["lockState"].ToString(), id = users[0]["id"].ToString(), withdrawal_request = users[0]["withdrawal_request"].ToString()};
    ContentPanel.DataContext = tcnobjects1;
 }
```

How to loop the items inside the grid ?i'm getting json data dynamically.using above code i can only display Json array **users[0]** elements only.help me with sample code of example.

Comment: i came across the similar kind of scenario .for me JSON.NET Documentaion helped me a lot  -just find http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsWindowsDataJson.htm link you may find solution

Answer (score -1):

hi the return type of the JArray is an array so you can able to get the length of the array and loop them as shown below

```
 //creating a list for tcnobjects
 List<tcnobjects1> objectsList=new List<tcnobjects1>();

 var users = JArray.Parse(data.Result.ToString());
//looping through the array elements
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
{
   tcnobjects1 = new TcnObjects1 {scheme = users[i]["scheme"].ToString(), units  = users[i]["units"].ToString(), amount = users[i]["amount"].ToString(),    currency = users[i]["currency"].ToString(), lockState = users[i]  ["lockState"].ToString(), id = users[i]["id"].ToString(), withdrawal_request =   users[i]["withdrawal_request"].ToString()};
   objectsList.add(tcnobjects1);
}
ContentPanel.DataContext =objectsList
```

i hope my answer is helpful :)

Comment: getting Binding Error:System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'scheme' property not found on 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Myapp.pendingtcn+TcnObjects1]' 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Myapp.pendingtcn+TcnObjects1]' (HashCode=49347015). BindingExpression: Path='scheme' DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Myapp.pendingtcn+TcnObjects1]' (HashCode=49347015); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='ab'); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..

Comment: did u get the data in objectsList?.just check with breakpoint and my solution was for looping through all items in the json

Comment: how to display that all items in xaml?

Comment: var t = JObject.Parse(result);

var x=  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

           XmlDocument doc =   (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(x);

this is one way whiich i used to convert json data

Comment: http://newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsWindowsDataJson.htm link will definitely help you bro.

Comment: json convertion is not my problem.my problem is to display the data in textblock using a **loop**.